# Create symlink for template folder for multiple Apache sites?

Tags: apache-2.2

For some insane reason, the web development company that built out a website I inherited created a separate Joomla installation for each department in a company rather than set up a proper multi-user, multi-section website, and now I have over 45 duplicated site template folders on an Apache server.

I would like to (for the short term) have one template folder with symlinks from all the other locations, so I can at least get that template under control (later I'll be working on rejigging the site and combining databases/users into one)... is this possible? If someone visits www.example.com/address2, would they be able to get the template from elsewhere on the server through a symlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to add the following to httpd.conf where you set up the directory:

```
Options +Followsymlinks
```

Comment: I will try this on one of the sites and see how it works - thanks!